# conda create environment command gives 'Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.'

Tags: python-2.7, conda, choco

I installed `miniconda` via `choco install miniconda3`.

Creating a python3 environment works fine.

```
conda create --name envA python=3 --verbose
```

But creating a python2 environment has a problem.

```
conda create --name envB python=2 --verbose
```

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working...
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
...

File "C:\Users\fred\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 352, in find_conflicts
    raise UnsatisfiableError(bad_deps, strict=strict_channel_priority)
conda.exceptions.UnsatisfiableError
```

Comment: in my experience, in the past these problems could often be solved by using mamba instead of conda, as it tends to give you better error messages. Generally speaking tho, python 2 is end-of-life and it might be hard to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cel gets credit for this

Switching to mamba provided better diagnostics.

```
mamba create -n foo python=2

Looking for: ['python=2']

conda-forge/win-64                                          Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache
Encountered problems while solving:
 - nothing provides vc 9.* needed by python-2.7.12-0
```

Then use mamba to find `vc`.

```
mamba search vc

# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
vc                              14.1      h21ff451_1  conda-forge
vc                              14.1      h6d1b3ff_2  conda-forge
...
```

The `vc v9` can be found in the `defaults` channel.

```
mamba search 'vc[channel=defaults]'

# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
vc                                 9      h2eaa2aa_6  pkgs/main
...
```

Updating the `.condarc` with the `defaults` channel, corrected the problem.

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
channel_priority: disabled
```

As a final note, should someone else find themselves in this situation...

The `~/.condarc` got changed (dropping the `defaults` channel) as part of installing `mambaforge`.

Comment: "*.condarc got damaged when I installed mambaforge*" - was it really damaged? or was it just replaced? Mambaforge is a Miniforge variant, which omits the **defaults** channel *by design*. Also, why was Mambaforge installed when there was already a Conda installation?

Comment: Whether it is damaged or not depends on perspective. From the mambaforge perspective it is fine. From the miniconda3 perspective it is damaged. The issue is related to what to do with the ~/.condarc file when both miniconda3 and mambaforge are installed. What should the two packages do during installation? I would think the thing to do is to create default ~/miniconda3/.condarc ~/mambaforge/.condarc respectively which would be discovered before the ~/.condarc file. Of course that might introduce other problems. In any case I will change my comment.